# Issue Using Mockito's When Method

Tags: java, mockito

I'm struggling trying to teach myself Mockito.

Consider the following method, *hasInventory()*, which should not really run in my way of thinking, but get set up to return *true* or *false* as I squirrel-cage my test. Class *Warehouse* is my "mocked-dependency".

```
public class Warehouse implements IWarehouse
{
  private Map< String, Integer >    inventory;

  public Warehouse()
  {
    this.inventory = new HashMap< String, Integer >();
  }

  public final boolean hasInventory( String itemname, int quantity )
      throws InventoryDoesNotExistException
  {
    if( inventory == null )
      throw new InventoryDoesNotExistException();

    if( !inventory.containsKey( itemname ) )
      return false;

    int current = ( inventory.containsKey( itemname ) ) ? inventory.get( itemname ) : 0;

    return( current >= quantity );
  }
  ...
```

In the JUnit test code, the first *when()* throws an exception because it literally interprets the method call (executing it) and, *inventory* being nil (see above), *InventoryDoesNotExistException* is thrown. There are other methods in the mocked-dependency class too, like *add()* and *remove()*.

```
@RunWith( MockitoJUnitRunner.class )
public class OrderInteractionTest
{
  private static final String TALISKER = "Talisker";
  private Order   systemUnderTest  = null;

  @Mock
  private Warehouse   mockedDependency = null;

  @Before
  public void init()
  {
    //MockitoAnnotations.initMocks( this );
    //mockedDependency = mock( Warehouse.class );
    this.systemUnderTest  = new Order( TALISKER, 50 );
  }

  @Test  
  public void testFillingRemovesInventoryIfInStock()  
  {  
    try  
    {  
      doNothing().doThrow( new RuntimeException() ).when( mockedDependency ).add( anyString(), anyInt() );  
      doNothing().doThrow( new RuntimeException() ).when( mockedDependency ).remove( anyString(), anyInt() );  
      when( mockedDependency.hasInventory( anyString(), anyInt() ) ).thenReturn( true );  
      when( mockedDependency.getInventory( anyString() ) ).thenReturn( 50 );
```

As I understand it, by the *when()* method, I'm asking Mockito precisely not to call *hasInventory()*, but just to return *true* instead whenever it's called as I test the class ("systemUnderTest"). Can anyone help me get past this point (or get some sense into my brain)?

I'm linking *mockito-all-1.8.5.jar* and JUnit 4.

Copious thanks to all who read this.

Russ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mockito cannot mock `final` classes or methods. Try removing the `final` modifier from the `hasInventory` method. Or better yet, do not mock the `Warehouse` class, instead mock the `IWarehouse` interface, whose methods cannot be `final`, and presumably defines those used by `Order`.

In general, it's preferable to mock interfaces, but it's not mandatory.

Not being able to mock `final` classes or methods is briefly mentioned in the Mockito [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/FAQ), it is due to the runtime class generation technique used for creating the mocks.

Comment: Ha! Yes, that's the problem. In fact, I read something about this earlier today, but I didn't make the connection. In imitation of other tutorials, I had begun to mock IWarehouse and that was working, so I figured I could only mock interfaces (I was talking to someone a few weeks back who told me I could mock simple classes, so I hadn't tried to mock the interface since I figured in many real-life scenarios, I wouldn't even have an interface). But this is the right answer! Thank you very much for this.